# Guessing a word (eg: **** *******)

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a piece of code that allows me to type in a letter and then checks if the letter belongs to the word. Then it should display the word with only the correct letter visible.

Example:

Word that I need to guess : jungle book

as displayed on screen: `***** ****`

letter that I am guessing: j

display on screen: `j**** ****`

and so on

What I've got so far:

```
public void guessConsonent()  {
    String guessedConsonent = consonentInput(); 
    // returns a letter

    wordInStars = ""; 

    for (int s = 0; s < secretWord.length(); s++)
        if (secretWord.substring(s, s+1).equals(guessedConsonent)) {
            wordInStars += guessedConsonent;
        } else if (woordVanCat.substring(s, s+1).equals(" ")) {
            wordInStars += " ";
        } else {
            wordInStars += "*";
        }
    System.out.println(wordInStars);
}
```

The problem is that it does not add the consonent to the word even if it's correct. I still only get ' ***'

regards

Comment: What is your question here

Comment: It does not work, it does not add the j to the word

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Given variable names are intended to be descriptive, and you are asking for help on a forum that is conducted in English, use English based attribute names.

Comment: I've added notes that say what each variable does, however I will change everything to English names. Give me a moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are writing a [hangman-clone in Java](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/267048/hangman-source-code-java). The snippet I don't see is:

```
if (wordVanCat.charAt(i) == a){
    woordSterRaden.setCharAt(i, a);
} else {
    woordSterRaden.setCharAt(i, '*');
}
```

Comment: it's actually a wheel of fortune game. With this code, i should change a into the consonent I'm guessing? what if there's a space? I don't want a space to become *. Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a regular expression check for letters, something like new String(a).lowerCase().matches("^[a-z]+");

Answer (score 0):

```
void guess() {
   Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
   String yes = "Hello World";
   String g = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < yes.length(); ++i) g += '*';
   while (!yes.equals(g)) {
       String resp = cin.next();
       String temp = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < yes.length(); ++i) {
           if (g.charAt(i) == '*' && yes.charAt(i) == resp.charAt(0))
              temp += resp.charAt(0);
           else
              temp += g.charAt(i);
       }
       g = temp;
   }
}
```